# Cannot disable spotlight indexing on volume

Tags: macos

I have a FAT32 partition on my HDD. When using OSX, it is mounted to `/Volumes/MEDIA`. After a recent upgrade to Mavericks, spotlight is having trouble indexing it, eating up almost all of my system resources, and I cannot get the indexing to stop:

```
[jay-mba-osx ~]% sudo mdutil -v -a -i off
/:
    Indexing disabled.
[jay-mba-osx ~]% sudo mdutil -v -V /Volumes/MEDIA -i off
[jay-mba-osx ~]% mdutil -v -a -s
/:
    Indexing disabled.
/Volumes/BOOTCAMP:
    Indexing disabled.
/Volumes/MEDIA:
    Indexing enabled.
[jay-mba-osx ~]%
[jay-mba-osx ~]% sudo mdutil -v -V /Volumes/MEDIA -E
/Volumes/MEDIA:
    Indexing enabled.
[jay-mba-osx ~]% sudo mdutil -v -V /Volumes/MEDIA -i off
[jay-mba-osx ~]% mdutil -v -a -s
/:
    Indexing disabled.
/Volumes/BOOTCAMP:
    Indexing disabled.
/Volumes/MEDIA:
    Indexing enabled.
[jay-mba-osx ~]%
```

How to I tell spotlight to "cease and desist" on my `MEDIA` volume? I only want or need spotlight indexing on my OSX partition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I disabled Spotlight on my `MEDIA` partition by adding it to the "Privacy" list in System Preferences -> Spotlight.

```
[jay-mba-osx ~]% mdutil -v -a -s
/:
    Indexing disabled.
/Volumes/BOOTCAMP:
    Indexing and searching disabled.
/Volumes/MEDIA:
    Indexing and searching disabled.
[jay-mba-osx ~]%
```

I don't know why this cannot be done through the `mdutil` command-line utility.